# TMap does not work as I expect with ZIO RC18-2

Tags: scala, stm, zio

I try to use `TMap` the following way:

Define the `TMap`:

```
val chatIdMapSTM: ChatIds = TMap.make(camunda_group -> camundaChatId, "pme123" -> 275469757L)
```

Put an entry:

```
def registerChat(maybeId: Option[ChatUserOrGroup], chatId: ChatId): ZIO[Any, RegisterException, String] =
  (for {
    chatStm <- chatIdMapSTM
    _ <- maybeId.map(id => chatStm.put(id, chatId)).getOrElse(chatIdMapSTM)
    values <- chatStm.values // List(1212, 275469757, -319641852)
  } yield chatStm).commit
    .as("your chat was successful registered")
```

Then try to get that value:

```
def requestChat(chatUserOrGroup: ChatUserOrGroup): UIO[ChatId] =
  (for {
    chatStm <- chatIdMapSTM
    values <- chatStm.values // List(275469757, -319641852)
    chatId <- chatStm.getOrElse(chatUserOrGroup, camundaChatId)
  } yield chatId).commit
```

As the comments suggests, when I request the entry, the new value is not there.

Do I miss something?

Comment: I don't know STM or ZIO but I'm curious why, for every `values` pulled from `chatStm.values`, do you yield `chatStm`? It's at least a pointless variable creation.

Comment: @jwvh you are right - I only added it to show the content of the map in each function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you've never committed the chat map, hence you're always "starting from scratch". See the following working example:

```scala
import zio._
import zio.console._
import zio.stm._

object ChatsExample extends App {
  def run(args: List[String]) =
    for {
      map  <- chatIdMapSTM.commit
      res  <- registerChat(map, "dejan", 123L)
      _    <- putStrLn(res)
      chat <- requestChat(map, "dejan")
      _    <- putStrLn(s"Found id: $chat")
      vals <- map.values.commit
      _    <- putStrLn(vals.mkString(","))
    } yield 0

  val camundaChatId = 0L
  val chatIdMapSTM  = TMap.make("camunda" -> camundaChatId, "pme123" -> 275469757L)

  def registerChat(chats: TMap[String, Long], userId: String, chatId: Long) =
    (chats.put(userId, chatId).as("your chat was successfully registered")).commit

  def requestChat(chats: TMap[String, Long], userId: String) =
    chats.getOrElse(userId, camundaChatId).commit
}
```

Comment: Thanks - my OO background got in the way. What I wanted to achieve is to have the TMap as the internals and not in the interface (I am using the Module pattern). Would something like this be possible https://gist.github.com/pme123/bdf9edc30e58afe22c6c7735437d45bb?

Comment: Yes. I would probably tweak the signatures of methods to avoid accepting option, but from the perspective of STM, this looks correct.

Comment: Also, you can "hide" the TMap completely by using `ZLayer.fromEffect`. This should work:

```scala
val live = 
  ZLayer.fromEffect {
    TMap.empty.commit.map { map =>
      new Service { ... }
    }
  }
```

Comment: `ZLayer.fromEffect` is what I was looking for - thanks. So I rewrote my code to https://gist.github.com/pme123/ecbad755c9ab6e1ec2f9a4681b16d7f8 Sadly still the same result!

Comment: Please take a look at the working example above, I tested that one and it works as expected. Regarding the layer, I would replace `def live` in your gist to `val live` as in mine, and I would encapsulate `TMap` there rather than constructing it outside.

Comment: Thanks I found my problem - I left a comment on Gist. But this would be another question;).